# AttributeError: module 'keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'populate_dict_with_module_objects' (Downgrade keras to 2.2.4 not working)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

This was working fine till yesterday with keras 2.2.4, i did train a model too so today i had to restart the runtime and i had to downgrade keras to 2.2.4 and when I import keras I get an error.

my tensorflow ver-2.5.0

```
pip install keras==2.2.4
```

- 

```
import keras
```

The error I get

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-88d96843a926> in <module>()
----> 1 import keras

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/initializers/__init__.py in populate_deserializable_objects()
     80     v2_objs = {}
     81     base_cls = initializers_v2.Initializer
---> 82     generic_utils.populate_dict_with_module_objects(
     83         v2_objs,
     84         [initializers_v2],

AttributeError: module 'keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'populate_dict_with_module_objects'
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the latest versions and change

```
keras.utils.generic_utils
```

to

```
tf.keras.utils.generic_utils
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to import Keras from Tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import layers
```

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso funcionó lo siguiente:

This is what I did to solve your problem:

```
pip uninstall -y tf-nightly

pip uninstall -y tf-estimate-nightly

pip install --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir tensorflow
```